# Unable to traverse through the array inside JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

If you open [this](https://telekom.jobs/globaljobboard_api/v3/search/%7B%22JobadID%22%3A%22%22%2C%22LanguageCode%22%3A%222%22%2C%22SearchParamters%22%3A%7B%22FirstItem%22%3A1%2C%22CountItem%22%3A1000%2C%22.json) link, you will get a JSON data. When I try to traverse through it I can perfectly get the data from the very first nodes, i.e: `"SearchResultCount" & "SearchResultCountAll"` and even the two elements inside the second object. But the problem occurs when I try to grab the data from `"JobCategory" & "CareerLevel" & "UserArea" descriptions` objects, I am traversing through them in this way :

```js
//Loaded through Casper JS
var doc = JSON.parse(this.getPageContent());

console.log(doc.SearchResult.SearchResultItems[0].MatchedObjectDescriptor.PositionTitle)
console.log(doc.SearchResult.SearchResultItems[0].MatchedObjectDescriptor.PositionURI)
console.log(doc.SearchResult.SearchResultItems[0].MatchedObjectDescriptor.JobCategory[0].Name)
console.log(doc.SearchResult.SearchResultItems[0].MatchedObjectDescriptor.CareerLevel[0].Name)
console.log(doc.SearchResult.SearchResultItems[0].MatchedObjectDescriptor.ParentOrganizationName)
console.log(doc.SearchResult.SearchResultItems[0].MatchedObjectDescriptor.UserArea.TextJobDescription +
  doc.SearchResult.SearchResultItems[0].MatchedObjectDescriptor.UserArea.TextRequirementDescription)
console.log(doc.SearchResult.SearchResultItems[0].MatchedObjectDescriptor.PublicationStartDate)
console.log(doc.SearchResult.SearchResultItems[0].MatchedObjectDescriptor.OrganizationName)
```

> The first two data's are displayed but the rest says,  `undefined is not an object`

I don't know what is the problem !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine for me. (Run the code snippet below)

```js
const url = 'https://telekom.jobs/globaljobboard_api/v3/search/%7B%22JobadID%22%3A%22%22%2C%22LanguageCode%22%3A%222%22%2C%22SearchParamters%22%3A%7B%22FirstItem%22%3A1%2C%22CountItem%22%3A1000%2C%22.json';
fetch(url).then(data => data.json()).then(doc => {

console.log(doc.SearchResult.SearchResultItems[0].MatchedObjectDescriptor.PositionTitle)
console.log(doc.SearchResult.SearchResultItems[0].MatchedObjectDescriptor.PositionURI)
console.log(doc.SearchResult.SearchResultItems[0].MatchedObjectDescriptor.JobCategory[0].Name)
console.log(doc.SearchResult.SearchResultItems[0].MatchedObjectDescriptor.CareerLevel[0].Name)
console.log(doc.SearchResult.SearchResultItems[0].MatchedObjectDescriptor.ParentOrganizationName)
console.log(doc.SearchResult.SearchResultItems[0].MatchedObjectDescriptor.UserArea.TextJobDescription +
  doc.SearchResult.SearchResultItems[0].MatchedObjectDescriptor.UserArea.TextRequirementDescription)
console.log(doc.SearchResult.SearchResultItems[0].MatchedObjectDescriptor.PublicationStartDate)
console.log(doc.SearchResult.SearchResultItems[0].MatchedObjectDescriptor.OrganizationName)

});
```

It's likely that your problem is in this.getPageContent().